# Pythonic way of finding RMS in large dataset

Tags: python, fluid-dynamics, parallel-computing

I am working on a fluid mechanics problem with a 4-D dataset (time,x,y,z). I am trying to find the RMS values such as $\overline{u^\prime u^\prime}$,$\overline{v^\prime v^\prime}$,$\overline{w^\prime w^\prime}$ etc., the standard procedure then is to decompose a quantity into its mean and fluctuating components $U = \overline{u} -u'$.

So currently what I've been doing is thus,

```
nt,nz,nx,ny = w.shape # grabbing the shape of the original data 

uprime = np.zeros((nt,nz,nx,ny))
vprime = np.zeros((nt,nz,nx,ny))
wprime = np.zeros((nt,nz,nx,ny))

for i in range(nt):
    wprime[i,:,:,:] = np.subtract(w[i,:,:,:],Wmean)
    uprime[i,:,:,:] = np.subtract(u[i,:,:,:],Umean)
    vprime[i,:,:,:] = np.subtract(v[i,:,:,:],Vmean)

vvprime = np.mean(vprime*vprime,axis=0)
uuprime = np.mean(uprime*uprime,axis=0)
wwprime = np.mean(wprime*wprime,axis=0)
```

The data is very large and I'm sure there is a more effective way to accomplish this task, my question then is there a more Pythonic way of writing this code or similar code?

Comment: I think scipy.stats should address it 
https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.stats.moment.html

Comment: You say "the data is very large", but is writing the code in this way actually a bottleneck for you? If it's not a bottleneck, then it's not worth addressing the question.

Answer (score 3):

To compute the mean squared error, use `np.var` applied along the `t` axis. So from your code snippet above.

```
np.var(w, axis=0) #contains uuprime, vvprime, and wwprime
```

To compute the root mean square, use `np.std`

```
np.std(w, axis=0) #contains sqrt(uuprime), sqrt(vvprime), and sqrt(wwprime)
```